# BIND MySQL / MyDNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, mysql, hosting, dns-hosting

Good afternoon,

after successfully failing to ask that Question on Stackoverflow, I have to post it here. Problem still exists.

I need your power for another project.

I want to have a DNS-Server, wich is in the Backend connected with a database (mysql pref.).

I tried to follw serval tutorials, but I often failed at the point where I have to install the following package:

libmysqlclient-dev

And because of no sense, there is no way to install mysql-server directly, only mariadb sever is working currently.

Does anyone of you out there can help me out of this problem?

Greetings

PS: Why database-backend? I want to create a webpanel for dns hosting due to to much domains I have to manage.

What I tried so far (reinstallations included):

Serval Linux-OS (Ubuntu 22.04, 18.04, 16.xx; CentOS 7, Debian 10)

Use mariadb instead of mysql server (doesnt matter wich of both, just working)

Gave up on MyDNS and hope on an Answer for bind with database

Both of those are failing at mysql-server and libmysqlclient-dev install .

Answer (score 0):

ISC Bind does not, as far as I know, include any native support for a a specific database backend.  As far as I know it only provides the bindings with DynDB https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter6.html#dynamic-database-dyndb

You will need third party extensions to provide a MySQL/MariaDB driver and associated database schema.

PowerDnS is commonly recommended as an alternative DNS server with native support/plugins for a number of different backends and includes MySQL IIRC

Comment: Thank you for your tip. PowerDNS seems to be a better choice, because there is also an option to do Dynamic DNS.